# Insert bytearray into bytearray Python

Tags: python, insert

I'm trying to insert one byte array into another at the beginning.  Here's a simple example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
import struct
a = bytearray(struct.pack(">i", 1))
b = bytearray(struct.pack(">i", 2))
a = a.insert(0, b)
print(a)
```

However this fails with the following error:

`a = a.insert(0, b)`
`TypeError: an integer is required`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`bytearray` is a sequence-type, and it supports slice-based operations. The "insert at position `i`" idiom with slices goes like this `x[i:i] = <a compatible sequence>`. So, for the *fist* position:

```
>>> a
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x01')
>>> b
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x02')
>>> a[0:0] = b
>>> a
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01')
```

For the *third* position:

```
>>> a
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x01')
>>> b
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x02')
>>> a[2:2] = b
>>> a
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x01')
```

Note, this isn't equivalent to `.insert`, because for sequences, `.insert` *inserts the entire object as the ith element*. So, consider the following simple example with lists:

```
>>> y = ['a','b']
>>> x.insert(0, y)
>>>
>>> x
[['a', 'b'], 1, 2, 3]
```

What you *really wanted* was:

```
>>> x
[1, 2, 3]
>>> y
['a', 'b']
>>> x[0:0] = y
>>> x
['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: @Russell because `.insert` tries to *insert the object, i.e. the entire bytearray* as the ith element. But that isn't what you want, bytearrays can only contain *bytes*, not bytearray-objects. Think of this: `x = [1,2,3]; y = ['a','b']; x.insert(0,y)` will give you `x == [['a', 'b'], 1, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = bytearray(struct.pack(">i", 1))
>>> b = bytearray(struct.pack(">i", 2))
>>> a = b + a
>>> a
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01')
```

Comment: Yes... but I actually need to insert occasionally at a non-zero index where concatenation might not work.

Answer (score 1):

[Bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray-objects) are mutable sequence of single bytes (integers), so bytearray only accepts integers that meet the value restriction 0 <= x <= 255):

```
>>> a = bytearray(struct.pack(">i", 1))
>>> b = bytearray(struct.pack(">i", 2))
>>> a.insert(0,b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required

>>> a=b+a
>>> a
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01')

>>>a[:2]=b
>>> a
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x01')
```

Comment: I couldn't understand why `a[:2]=b` was giving the result `bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x01')` for `a`. Indeed if executed after `a=b+a` the result will be `bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01')`. This example is not a sequence!