# Python 3.73 inserting into bytearray = "object cannot be re-sized"

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-bytearray

I'm working with a bytearray from file data.  I'm [opening](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#open) it as `'r+b'`, so can change as binary.

In the [Python 3.7 docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#finding-all-adverbs-and-their-positions), it explains that a RegEx's `finditer()` can use `m.start()` and `m.end()` to identify the start and end of a match.

In the question [Insert bytearray into bytearray Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46331220/insert-bytearray-into-bytearray-python), the answer says an insert can be made to a bytearray by using slicing.  But when this is attempted, the following error is given: `BufferError: Existing exports of data: object cannot be re-sized`.

Here is an example:

```
    pat = re.compile(rb'0.?\d* [nN]')   # regex, binary "0[.*] n"
    with open(file, mode='r+b') as f:   # updateable, binary
        d = bytearray(f.read())         # read file data as d [as bytes]
        it = pat.finditer(d)            # find pattern in data as iterable
        for match in it:                # for each match,
            m = match.group()           # bytes of the match string to binary m
            ...
            val = b'0123456789 n'
            ...
            d[match.start():match.end()] = bytearray(val)
```

In the file, the match is `0 n` and I'm attempting to replace it with `0123456789 n` so would be inserting 9 bytes. The file *can* be changed successfully with this code, just not *increased* in size. What am I doing wrong?  Here is output showing all non-increasing-filesize operations working, but it failing on inserting digits:

```
*** Changing b'0.0032 n' to b'0.0640 n'
len(d): 10435, match.start(): 607, match.end(): 615, len(bytearray(val)): 8
*** Found: "0.0126 n"; set to [0.252] or custom:
*** Changing b'0.0126 n' to b'0.2520 n'
len(d): 10435, match.start(): 758, match.end(): 766, len(bytearray(val)): 8
*** Found: "0 n"; set to [0.1] or custom:
*** Changing b'0 n' to b'0.1 n'
len(d): 10435, match.start(): 806, match.end(): 809, len(bytearray(val)): 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fixV1.py", line 190, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "fixV1.py", line 136, in main
    nchanges += search(midfile)     # perform search, returning count
  File "fixV1.py", line 71, in search
    d[match.start():match.end()] = bytearray(val)
BufferError: Existing exports of data: object cannot be re-sized
```

Comment: what are the values of `len(d)`, `match.start()`, `match.end()` and `len(bytearray(val))`?

Comment: what is this part of regex `0.?\d*` mean to you ?

Comment: RegEx `0.?\d* [nN]` means "data starts with a `0`, has an optional `.`, and 0 or more digits. Then is followed by a " " character, and either an `n` or `N`."  It appears to be matching correctly in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple case, much like modifying an iterable during iteration:

- `it = pat.finditer(d)` [creates a buffer](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d36cf5f1d20ce9f111a8fc997104785086e8eee6/Modules/_sre.c#L375) from the bytearray object. This in turn "locks" the bytearray object from being changed in size.
- `d[match.start():match.end()] = bytearray(val)` attempts to modify the size on the "locked" bytearray object.

Just like attempting to change a list's size while iterating over it will fail, an attempt to change a bytearray size while iterating over it's buffer will also fail.

You can give a copy of the object to `finditer()`.

For more information about buffers and how Python works under the hood, see the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#buffer-protocol).

---

Also, do keep in mind, you're not actually modifying the file. You'll nee to either write the data back to the file, or use [memory mapped files](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html). I suggest the latter if you're looking for efficiency.

Comment: The idea was (at first) to open the file, read it (into [d]), modify it by adding bytes, then write it back.  But this fails on the slicing-insert, not on the file save.  In  the docs for MMAP, it reads "# note that new content must have same size."  I guess the question becomes, can [d] be created as non-locked?

Comment: @rdtsc length can be changed. Yes, it fails on the slice-insert cause it's locked. The only way to do this is by creating a copy of the data, either immediately or lazily.Try doing `it = pat.finditer(d.copy())` you'll see it'll work.